# ST_ColorMap problem in postgis

Tags: postgis

I run into ST_ColorMap problem in postgis.

Here is the code fragment:

```
r22=> WITH  sfpoly  AS ( SELECT ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(( 3727069.4991851943 4256930.979258035 , 4002242.8010118287 4256930.979258035 , 4002242.8010118287 4440379.847142459 , 3727069.4991851943 4440379.847142459 , 3727069.4991851943 4256930.979258035 ))',3857),4326) as geom), r AS ( SELECT ST_Union(srtm.rast)AS rast FROM o_4_rdepivm1 as srtm JOIN sfpoly sf ON ST_Intersects(srtm.rast::geometry, sf.geom) ),  cx AS (SELECT ST_AsRaster(sf.geom, r.rast) AS rast FROM sfpoly sf CROSS JOIN r )  SELECT  ST_AsPNG(ST_ColorMap(ST_Clip(r.rast, sf.geom), ' 100% 190 185 135  50% 240 250 150  ')) AS rast FROM r CROSS JOIN cx CROSS JOIN sfpoly sf where r.rast is not null;
NOTICE:  More than five elements in colormap entry 1. Using at most five elements
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_colormap(raster,integer,text,text) line 85 at RETURN
NOTICE:  Method INTERPOLATE requires at least two non-NODATA colormap entries. Using NEAREST instead
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_colormap(raster,integer,text,text) line 85 at RETURN
```

Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

By reading the examples from http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_ColorMap.html you should have new line between the two colormap entries in your

`' 100% 190 185 135 50% 240 250 150 '`.

Now it it looks like PostGIS is finding just one entry with 8 elements and therefore the error:

```
NOTICE: More than five elements in colormap entry
```

Comment: Thank you user30184. Now I understood the issue. Each item should be in new line